# How to create a dag every day of the week but not run automatically?

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

I have a main DAG that launches a series of tasks, for example:
T1> T2> T3> T4> T5> T6> T7

But it happens that sometimes you have to re-execute a task, not because it is wrong, because there have been changes, but when you relaunch that you want to relaunch others related to it, for example:

If I re-launch the T3 task once I finish I want T4 and T5 to pass, currently I would have to clear those three tasks in Airflow for each day that I have to execute.

I want to create an auxiliary DAG for those three tasks, which is created automatically for each day but is not launched, and when I want to launch it, I simply go to the DAG of that day and launch the execution.

Comment: I am not quite following but when you do `clear` you can select `Past` or `Future` to `clear` for all past days or all future days from where you selected.  At least this will save you from clear for each day.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Emma Thanks for your answer, it is helpful. Let me explain, I would have to restart several tasks, but there are others that I do not want to restart, I would like to make a DAG that contains only those n dependent tasks, in such a way that a clear launches the 3 tasks and not have to do a clear for each task

Comment: @Emma Basically i want schedule a DAG, but not trigger it

Comment: You can first pause (toggle button) the DAG, then you clear 1 task with `Past` or `Future` *selected*, and `upstream`, `downstream` *unselected*.  Do the same thing for 2 other tasks.  And then you can check in Tree view that all tasks you want to rerun is in white or light green boxes.  If that is correct, you can now resume the DAG.  Does it answer your scenario?